WireGuardKitC.h failing to compile in Xcode 16.0
My build was working fine in xcode 15.4, after updating to 16.0, this problem is occurring.
Could not find any reference for DarwinFoundation anywhere, any help or suggestion is welcome.
~/Sources/WireGuardKitC/WireGuardKitC.h:10:5 Declaration of 'u_int32_t' must be imported from module 'DarwinFoundation.unsigned_types.u_int32_t' before it is required
~/Sources/WireGuardKitC/WireGuardKitC.h:14:5 Declaration of 'u_char' must be imported from module 'DarwinFoundation.unsigned_types.u_char' before it is required
~/Sources/WireGuardKitC/WireGuardKitC.h:16:5 Declaration of 'u_int16_t' must be imported from module 'DarwinFoundation.unsigned_types.u_int16_t' before it is required
/// WireGuardKitC.h source ///
#include "key.h"
#include "x25519.h"

/* From <sys/kern_control.h> */
#define CTLIOCGINFO 0xc0644e03UL
struct ctl_info {
    u_int32_t   ctl_id;
    char        ctl_name[96];
};
struct sockaddr_ctl {
    u_char      sc_len;
    u_char      sc_family;
    u_int16_t   ss_sysaddr;
    u_int32_t   sc_id;
    u_int32_t   sc_unit;
    u_int32_t   sc_reserved[5];
};

problem was occurring in iOS projects for Wireguard implementation.
It was working fine in Xcode 15.4, stopped working in 16.0.

Have you found a solution for this?

solved it by adding #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> at top

If anybody is still wandering, just adding
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

at top will fix the issue.

a more universal solution would be to to #include <sys/types.h>

there is currently a pending upstream pull request with the fix applied: https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-apple/pull/33

Hey! Yes I did the PR you linked but no signs of Jason whatsoever on the Apple related repos...

sys/types didn't work for me.  But Foundation worked. Thanks

Having the same issue I made the change to this
struct ctl_info {
    int   ctl_id;
    char        ctl_name[96];
};
struct sockaddr_ctl {
    char      sc_len;
    char      sc_family;
    int   ss_sysaddr;
    int   sc_id;
    int   sc_unit;
    int   sc_reserved[5];
};

hope that help you or at least the next person who gets here

This helps build the project, but the wireguard does not connect. Were you able to connect with wireguard after this change @Thomas?

solved it by adding #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> at top

Simply add the following line at the top of the WireGuardKitC.h file:
#include <sys/types.h>
Here's a working example:
WireGuardKitC.h
#include <sys/types.h> // New line here


#include "key.h"
#include "x25519.h"


/* From <sys/kern_control.h> */
#define CTLIOCGINFO 0xc0644e03UL
struct ctl_info {
    u_int32_t   ctl_id;
    char        ctl_name[96];
};
struct sockaddr_ctl {
    u_char      sc_len;
    u_char      sc_family;
    u_int16_t   ss_sysaddr;
    u_int32_t   sc_id;
    u_int32_t   sc_unit;
    u_int32_t   sc_reserved[5];
};


Ivan Semkin already mentioned this.
